# How to record Desktop screen in UWP

Tags: uwp, screen, desktop, recording

how to record a video of desktop screen in Universal Windows Platform application including actions performed on App and Desktop Window also

Comment: This is now possible as of 1803.  What I'm trying to work out, because the samples on MS docs is so weak, is how to actually record the screen and interactions as a video file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, it goes against the sandboxing, security, etc.